# Cannot query data in Kibana APM

Tags: kibana, apm

java elastic-agent can access the apm-server normally,
and there is data reported by the agent in the apm index,
but why the kibana apm ui cannot query the data

es kibana apm-server versions are 7.17.5

[apm index data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zpQ.png) |[kiban apm ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd917.png) | [java agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JBro.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well I reinstalled a new es and it worked, I guess there might be a problem with the apm-server initialization index